# (Unity) How to read old game data on Android?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sharedpreferences

I created and published a game for android with AndEngine three years ago. Now I am preparing the game again with unity. When I send an update, all of the old data is deleted. Because Unity using 'PlayerPrefs' and Android using 'SharedPreferences'.
So, How do I read old data with Unity?

Here is my old code setup:

```
private SharedPreferences data;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

// ======================================================================

public void setup(Activity activity) {
    data = activity.getSharedPreferences("kayit", 0);
    editor = data.edit();
}
```

Comment: I can't tell exactly what you're talking about because Android do not delete PlayerPrefs data when you update the game

Comment: When I was writing the game in Andengine, I used the name "kayit" to save the data. (getSharedPreferences("kayit", 0)) But Unity used default location. For that reason, I cannot access the old data and all data is refreshed when the game is updated.

Comment: It seems like you're not using Unity engine but Andengine. If this is true then don't tag Unity

Comment: 1) I wrote and published the game with Andengine.
2) Naturally I stored the save data with "SharedPreferences".
3) I'm rewriting the game with Unity right now. Unity does not read the old game's data..  Because it uses "PlayerPrefs".
4) Therefore, when I send an update, all the data of the people playing the game are reset. 5) So, I need like this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36721931/getting-shared-preferences-while-migrating-project-from-cocos2dx-to-unity-androi)

Comment: If that's the case then show your old save and load script in Java. You have to show what it looks like

Comment: I found the data XML file, but I can't load. (I don't have much experience with this) I will write here if I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void ReadAndroidSharedPreferences(string packageName, string xmlDataName)
{
    string path = "/data/data/" + packageName + "/shared_prefs/" + xmlDataName + ".xml";

    FileStream levelFile = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open);
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

    string xmlText = "";

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(levelFile))
    {
        string line = null;
        do
        {
            line = sr.ReadLine();
            xmlText = xmlText + line + "\n";
        } while (line != null);

        sr.Close();
        levelFile.Close();
    }

    xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlText);
    var baseNode = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;

    foreach (XmlNode node in baseNode.ChildNodes)
    {
        Debug.Log("Type: " + node.Name);

        if (node.Attributes["name"] != null)
            Debug.Log("name: " + node.Attributes["name"].Value);
        else
            Debug.Log("Empty");

        if (node.Attributes["value"] != null)
            Debug.Log("Value: " + node.Attributes["value"].Value);
        else
            Debug.Log("Empty");
    }
}
```

Usage:
packageName = "com.yourcompany.yourgame"
xmlDataName = getSharedPreferences file name (in my question, it's "kayit")
You can see all 'int' and 'bool' data on Android Device Monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its going to be easy accessing persistent data saved with a different engine - but a solution I can see is release an update with the old engine that will upload the data to a remote server, and then download it using Unity, but since you already released the unity version that might not work for you

Comment: He wrote that he found a way here; [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36721931/getting-shared-preferences-while-migrating-project-from-cocos2dx-to-unity-androi) , but for Cocos2D. I don't know the working for Andengine.

Answer (score 0):

PlayerPrefs and SharedPreferences are different things.

But there is a solution.
Unity allows to add native android Java or C++ code to your Unity project and use interfaces to access that code. 
So you can write some code using Android SDK/NDK methods to access your SharedPreferences and add it as JAR or AAR to your Unity project.

Read about it in the official documentation https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html

Comment: Thanks for answer..I've seen it before. But it was a little long. For now, I will handle a shorter solution.